# Error - No Such Element Exception - when using ImplicityWait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Error - Not Visible Exception Was Unhandled][image: Error - No Such Element Exception]

Here is the code. I have attached the image of the error message:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BBC_W_FCast_New_01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather");

            //Using the 'Find a Forecast' search field to get the weather in 'Reading, UK'
            var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator-form-search"));

            //Use "Reading, Reading" to avoid ambiguity. There is a location called Reading in USA
            user.SendKeys("Reading, Reading");

            //Click on Search button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator-form-submit")).Click();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            //Click on Table button
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[10]")).Click();

            //Obtaining pressure For 2100 hours today
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[10]")).Click();

            //Obtain pressure for 2100 Hours tomorrow
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Click();

            //Subtract the two values above and then 'echo' the result in Selenium
            int val1 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Text);
            int val2 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[10]")).Text);

            int difference = val1 - val2;
System.Console.WriteLine("Difference is: " + difference);
```

---

In Java & they do not offer good enough answers:

- [Selenium Webdriver: No such element exception even though element gets available after waiting for some time](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13474/selenium-webdriver-no-such-element-exception-even-though-element-gets-available)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium

---

I get an error message on adding this code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("locator")));
```

I have added an internal class. But I am getting the error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in BBC_W_FCast_New_01.exe 
>   Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented."

The error comes from this particular line of code:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Here is the class:

```
internal class WebDriverWait
{
    private FirefoxDriver driver;
    private TimeSpan timeSpan;

    public WebDriverWait(FirefoxDriver driver, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.timeSpan = timeSpan;
    }

    internal IWebElement Until(object p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Either your locator is wrong or you need to use ExplicitWait, as already answered.

Comment: I have used the explicit wait. But I still get errors. I have added an internal class:

    internal class WebDriverWait
    {
        private FirefoxDriver driver;
        private TimeSpan timeSpan;

        public WebDriverWait(FirefoxDriver driver, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            this.timeSpan = timeSpan;
        }

        internal IWebElement Until(object p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from ImplicitlyWait to Explicitly wait for the element you want as detailed at http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Example:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Comment: I added an explicit Wait. But I get an error message. I have added it above. The information from my research is not clear to be honest. I have tried adding Selenium Wait classes to my project & I get the same error. What are your thoughts, please.

Comment: I see the code but not what error message you are getting?  Also please consider posing this as additional / separate question rather than changing original.  We want the question and answer to be clear and helpful for others that run into the same situation.

Comment: The error is: "ElementNotVisible Exception Was Unhandled". I added the question to the one below that which I posted earlier. I actually did not change the original. A screen shot of the error message is the first one at the top of the web page.

Thank you very much.